# Postman works but the form in the browser doesn't

Tags: node.js, multer

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="/uploadprofilepic" key="file" name="file" class="bg bg-light rounded position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle" style="margin-top: 25%;width: 40%;">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6"style="margin-bottom: 5%;">
        <label for="inputEmail4" style="margin-left: 4%;" >Email</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file" id="file" key="file" placeholder="file" accept="image/*">
      </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" key="file"  name="file" style="margin-top: 2%; margin-left: 2%; margin-bottom: 2%;" value="Sign Up"></input>
</form>
```

App.js

```
app.post("/uploadprofilepic",upload.single("file"),async (request,response,next)=>{
  try {
   
    const storageRef = ref(storage, `${request.file.originalname}`);
    
    // Create file metadata including the content type
    const metadata = {
        contentType: request.file.mimetype
    };
    
    // Upload the file in the bucket storage
    const snapshot =  await uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, request.file.buffer, metadata);
    //by using uploadBytesResumable we can control the progress of uploading like pause, resume, cancel
    // Grab the public url
    const downloadURL =  await getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref);
    return response.redirect("/")
```

Tried everything googled it and I'm at a loss when I use postman the picture uploads but when using the browser, I get "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'originalname')".

I've tried everything I've found on google